# Migrating process between arm and x86

Tags: linux, x86, arm, checkpoint

Does somebody have the knowledge that whether it is possible to migrate a process from an arm based system to x86 based. Both are running linux but the problem is in ARM the process state is different than the x86 one.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. x86 executables won't run on ARM, or vice versa, without some sort of binary translation or emulation.

Binary translation won't work for process migration because not all process states will match up between the two architectures. For instance, the translation process may combine some instructions in the translation process, so a process that's in the middle of an instruction pair that got combined won't have any equivalent state in the translated executable.

Emulation could *theoretically* work, but you'd still be taking the performance hit of emulation of course, and you'd also need to develop some kind of emulator that let you start from an arbitrary state (for migration). I'm not aware of any that'd be suitable here.

Comment: I was guessing this also. As for starting the process I think libhoudini can start and run an ARM binary on x86. But I was thinking of migration. The emulator (qemu) performance  is not matching my needs. So was thinking if there is some way to directly transform the process state. But the problem is the difference in register set.

Answer (score 1):

ARM can't run x86 instructions, and x86 can't run ARM instructions.  The problem isn't just different register set:  It's a whole different ABI.  Mapping ARM registers to x86 isn't even close to solving the problem.  You need a full emulation layer to run ARM binaries on x86.  The same system calls will have different numbers in at least some cases, so even just emulating an ARM CPU isn't enough.  You have to emulate the ARM ABI if the process is going to make system calls to an x86-64 kernel.

Your only real option is to migrate between ARM hardware and an ARM VM/emulator on x86 hardware, or vice-versa.  Either ARM linux running inside a full emulated VM, or a user-mode-only emulation that translates system calls.  The latter could probably be sped up more by a JIT-compiler that generated x86 machine code instead of interpreting insn by insn.  (JIT would work for both, but having to translate a full ARM-linux kernel in a full VM would be more work for the JIT layer.)

As duskwuff says, migration would have to be done in terms of the native machine state of the process, e.g. by a checkpointing library used by your ARM program.  This would ensure you don't run into problems with the binary-translated representation of your ARM state being inconsistent.